# How to tune neo4j.properties based on neo4j data store size?

Tags: neo4j

I'm playing around with neo4j. When I have a big database in size (12G) I see the following message in messges.log and neo4j server is not responsive anymore.

GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 134ms [total block time: 11.249s]

I believe by changing neo4j.propeties I would be able to tune Neo4j so that it would work fine with my database.
I was wondering if there is any guide how to tune Neo4j server?
I'm using windows and 16gb RAM

Comment: Well, have you looked at the [official documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.1/embedded-configuration.html)?

Comment: Yes, I did look at that. And I increased the heap size of Neo4j to 15gb. But still I'm getting the same error. (It doesn't happen all the time though).

Comment: Ok, I'm definitely no expert in Java Memory Management, so I can only suggest reading [up](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/useful-jvm-flags-part-1-jvm-types-and-compiler-modes/) [on](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) [it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) and trying out some settings to see if you get better results. Activate GC logging, use a [GC Viewer](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html) and create a repeatable test setup.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your graph.db/messages.log on a public link (dropbox or so), it seems you have too little heap? What is your server RAM, heap config and mmio config currently?

Comment: The server RAM is 16G and I've added these 3 lines to neo4j-wrapper.conf file:
wrapper.java.initmemory=15360
wrapper.java.maxmemory=15360
wrapper.java.additional=-Xmx14G
Here is the link to message.log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zch2jnbqb3wl0p3/message.log

Comment: Could you see if the messages only occur when doing cypher queries? I had a problem with particular queries being slow and taking up to much heap space.

Comment: What kind of queries are You running? The approach could be costly.